# HTTP request - Response was a server error. what does this mean?

Tags: http, httprequest, httpresponse, fiddler

i am trying to debug and issue and while examining HTTP request in Fiddler i noticed one of the request with a red triangle sign next to it with no HTTP response. Can someone explain what does it mean? is there an issue on our end or the server where the request was sent?

[image: Http Error in Fiddler]

TIA

Comment: I also noticed the request header has method set to none. what does that mean? it would be great if someone can help this newbie in understanding as to what's going on with this request.

Comment: This is a malformed request. What sent it? can you share a SAZ file?

Comment: Hi Eric.I have xml file and i was using fiddler to analyse the issue. Do you have email address where i can send the xml file?what do u mean by malformed request?

Comment: Can you post more information about what the application is doing that sends that request, and also what the server is doing that receives it? Without more information, perhaps this is related: http://blog.httpwatch.com/2008/01/28/what-does-aborted-mean-in-httpwatch/

Comment: Hi pieman. The application is a website and fires a javascript to send request to analytics(coremetrics) server. they are image requests. usually when i examine the image requests sent(using http xml files with fiddler)  i see response as 200 but this time i came across image request with no server response and the request header has method set to NONE instead of GET.I am just trying to wrap my head around what could've gone wrong. is it an issue on application end or analytics server end. Thanks.

Comment: File > Save Session Archive. Use Help > Send Feedback in Fiddler to send it to me. The core problem here is that the client (whatever it is) sent a request with malformed headers.

Comment: Thanks Eric. i've sent the info with screenshots at fiddler email address.

Answer (score 0):

The trace file you sent me shows that you've exported the traffic from IE's F12 Developer Tools `Network` tab, rather than capturing it with Fiddler itself. You then imported that traffic into Fiddler.

The problem is that the IE developer tools have a number of bugs and in this case they've omitted some of the request data. As a consequence, Fiddler shows only the data it finds and omits the missing data.

To get a proper capture, your best bet is to use Fiddler itself rather than the F12 tools.